# Converting elements of String[] to Scanner object

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to Java, and what I've been trying to do:

`tempTrailerArr`is a String[] = {"12.0 1.1", "24.51", "34.12", "82.87 231.2 1.1 2.2"}

Each element of `tempTrailerArr` is converted into a Scanner object `trScan`.

The first double of each element in tempTrailerArr is to be stored in a Double[] called `trailerVals`.

So the desired result would be for `tempTrailerArr` = {12.0 24.51 34.12 82.87}

However, the code below won't terminate, and I don't understand why?

```
        for (int j=0; j<tempTrailerArr.length; j++) {
        Scanner trScan = new Scanner(tempTrailerArr[j]);
        switch (j) {
        case 0: 
        case 1: 
        case 2: 
        case 3: this.trailerVals[j] = trScan.nextDouble();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It terminates for me.

Comment: It works fine for me. Please post a *complete* example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "just cast the value from String to double after you split it" - you'd need to use the Double.parseDouble(String s) to convert the string to to a double (if you went with this other approach.)

```
String [] tempTrailerArr =  {"12.0 1.1", "24.51", "34.12", "82.87 231.2 1.1 2.2"};

String [] tempTrailerVals = null;
double[] trailerVals = new double [tempTrailerArr.length];

for (int i = 0 ; i < tempTrailerArr.length ; i ++)
{
    tempTrailerVals = tempTrailerArr[i].split(" ");
    // you should also add some error handling here - what if we can't convert the value to a double?
    trailerVals[i] = Double.parseDouble(tempTrailerVals[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the split function and split the strings on the " " (space).

Hence you don't need a Scanner, just cast the value from String to double after you split it.

Answer (score 0):

to explain your code :

```
// loop start :
for (int j=0; j<tempTrailerArr.length; j++) {

    // creating a new Scanner object every time this loop starts
    // this scanner starts scanning the String value received from this element in the array
    Scanner trScan = new Scanner(tempTrailerArr[j]);

    // checks for the numerical value of J :
    switch (j) {

    // if j == 0, nothing happens, and go for the next case (no break mentioned)
    case 0: 

    // if j == 1, nothing happens, and go for the next case (no break mentioned)
    case 1: 

    // if j == 2, nothing happens, and go for the next case (no break mentioned)
    case 2: 

    // if j == 3 (and this will be true in case 0, case 1, case 2) 
    // trailerVals[j] = next double (if no double was found, an "InputMismatchException will be thrown
    // to use nextDouble(), first you should check if trScan.hasNextDouble(),
    // if true, then add double, else do nothing
    case 3: this.trailerVals[j] = trScan.nextDouble();

    // every time j will be less than or equal to 3, it will reach this point
       break;
    }
}
```

i explained your code because this was your question, but if you want to divide your String array into parts, use the String.split() method, or use a (for:each) loop and check the value and add it to the required array

please dont try to proceed in this code, it's lots of effort for nothing